# how do a create a good routing file

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner in `symfony2` `v2.8` , I created a handle, I configured the router and the controller but the following error is displayed:

> The "BlogBundle" (from the _controller value
>   "BlogBundle:Public:index") does not exist or is not enabled in your
>   kernel! Did you mean "TutoBlogBundle:Public:index"?

**my file routing.yml**

```
Blog_home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Public:index }
```

**my file controller**

```
namespace Tuto\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
Class PublicController extends Controller {

    function indexAction(){
        return new Response("Accueil du blog");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion, Symfony documentation about [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#routing-configuration) recommends to make use of annotation for routing.

Comment: Another suggestion... be careful with common errors when you copy&paste examples... Your bundle is under Tuto\BlogBundle namespace, so you must point  to it with the full namespace `_controller: TutoBlogBundle:Public:index`

Answer (score 1):

Your routing file should include the namespace too.

Try it like this

```
Blog_home:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: TutoBlogBundle:Public:index }
```

And it should be fine.

Comment: # src\Tuto\BlogBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml
Blog_home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Public:index }

Comment: Be careful with indent in yaml files, they are sensitive.

Comment: Did you add to Kernel TutoBlogBundle?

Comment: To , `app / AppKernel.php`